# Setting Environmental Variables to configure ANT,JAVA and TOMCAT

Tags: java, ant, environment-variables

Recently I have been trying to make changes so I can do builds through Ant and the command line. This has forced me to reconfigure my setup. In order to make java available on the class path  I typed the following in the command propmt...

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\JDK 1.6.0_08
```

that being the directory of my java installation. Then I will set my ANT_HOME variable to
the following

```
set ANT_HOME=C:\Ant
```

I can check both of these following doing this by doing

```
javac
```

and

```
ant
```

on the command line and getting the usual output signifying that they are being read.Following this I will set them both on the

```
path
```

by doing the following

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

After doing this I check the command line for each of them and they will work fine.

The problem that I am having is that randomly, I will go back and do the same command, and it will tell me that

```
"ant" is not recognized as an internal or external command...
```

I know this is the message you get when you type an incorrect command. Why is is that every website, tutorial and book I look at for configuring these services tells me to do the same process and none of them are working? Am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Windows remember that any changes that are made in a command window *only endure until the window is closed*.

Go to `My Computer --> Properties --> Advanced --> Environment Variables` and configure your variables here instead.

After that, close your command line window and open it again... Windows should now be able to recognize your commands.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not that it wont recognize the commands initially, it is that after it has recognized them, I will go back at an arbitrary time, and it wont recognize one of them anymore.

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum ...and setting them in My Computer / Properties etc. instead of using `set` on the command line solves that problem. Did you try it out?

Answer (score 2):

Setting environment variables in a console will only set them for the current process.  So when you close the console, or run a different console, you will lose your changes.

Make sure you aren't doing that, and make sure something else you are running isn't changing the system path.

I would suggest creating a start-up script for your build that contains the environment settings.  I create one named "ant.bat" at the root of my build tree.  This way it doesn't matter if the environment is set, you can always find a bat file in the current directory.  It will take care of setting the environment and calling ant.

Something like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\JDK 1.6.0_08
set ANT_HOME=C:\Ant

set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

call %ANT_HOME%\bin\ant %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

This also has the advantage of documenting the environment needed for the build.